# Insert value to stdClass

Tags: php

Trying to add months to years in an stdClass so it would look something like

- 2013

  - jan
  - feb 
    etc...
- 2014

  - jan
  - feb 
    etc...
- 2015

  - jan
  - feb 
    etc...

With the following code:

```
$months = array(
             1=>'jan',
             2=>'feb',
             3=>'mars',
             4=>'april',
             5=>'may',
             6=>'june',
             7=>'july',
             8=>'aug',
             9=>'sep',
             10=>'oct',
             11=>'nov',
             12=>'dec');

foreach($months as $month){
        echo strtr($month,$months) .'<br>';
}

$years = array('2013',
               '2014',
               '2015');

$data = new stdClass;

foreach($years as $year){
    $data->year[] = $year;
    foreach($months as $month){
        $data->month[] = $months;
    }
}

foreach($data as $value){
    echo 'Year: '.$value->year.'<br>';
    echo 'Month: '.$value->month.'<br>';
}
```

But the var_dump is hard to read, seems as its adding everything up to 37 times. Don't really know what I'm doing wrong (Or am i doing everything wrong?)

Comment: Okay. First of all. What's with echo strtr($month,$months) .'<br>';? Why not, just echo $month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all that is needed, though you need to show an actual `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of what you expect:

```
$data = new stdClass;

foreach($years as $year){
    $data->$year = $months;
}
```

Then:

```
foreach($data as $year => $months) {
    echo 'Year: '.$year.'<br>';
    foreach($months as $month) {
        echo 'Month: '.$month.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code can be reduced to:

```
<?php
$year = 2013;
while($year < 2016){
    echo $year;
    echo "<ul>";
for($i=1; $i < 13; $i++){
    $month = DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $i);
    echo "<li>".$month->format('M') . "</li>";
}
    echo "</ul>";
$year++;    
}
?>
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

[image]